# Overleaf, How do I insert a \definesubmol with hooks "?" in a parent structure multiple times?

Tags: chemfig

I have defined a submol for TEDA so that it can be inserted via !{TEDA} into a parent structure (Hexamethylbenzene).

```
\definesubmol{TEDA}{-[::60]*6(\chemabove{\textcolor{blue}{N}}{\scriptstyle{+}}?---\textcolor{blue}{N}(-[::150,.7]-[::-30,.7]?)--?)
```

This works perfectly fine as long as I do it once, but leads to undesired bonds with a vertex when I insert more than one.

1. TEDA : `\chemfig[][scale=.5]{!{TEDA}}`
2. TEDA+Parent : `\chemfig[][scale=.5]{*6((-!{TEDA})-(-)=(-)-(-)=(-)-(-)=)}`
3. 2*TEDA+Parent : `\chemfig[][scale=.5]{*6((-!{TEDA})-(-)=(-!{TEDA})-(-)=(-)-(-)=)}`

I already know that this must be caused by my TEDA definition, which contains hooks "?", which end up connecting among themselves, if I add more than one TEDA unit.

Is there a way to specify unique hooks for a single !{TEDA} instance? Do I need to tackle the problem in a different way entirely?

[image: The various results of 1., 2. and 3.]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! May I suggest to change the title? I can't see how "overleaf" is important here, you may just scare away some of those who could answer this question. More importantly, could you provide us with a minimal compilable document that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}` and illustrates the issue?

Answer (score 1):

From v1.33, you can define submols with argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\definesubmol{TEDA}1{-[::60]\chemabove{\textcolor{blue}{N}}{\rlap{\kern0.2em$\scriptstyle{+}$}}?[#1]*6(---\textcolor{blue}{N}(-[::150,.7]-[::-30,.7]?[#1])--?[#1])}
\chemfig{*6((-!{TEDA}{a})-(-)=(-!{TEDA}{b})-(-)=(-)-(-)=)}
\end{document}
```

[image]