# Connecting repeating fragments of the molecular structure possessing rotational symmetry with chemfig

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

While drawing a structure of a [hexabenzocoronene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexabenzocoronene) derivative, I decided to start with the central benzene ring, then define repeating fragment via `\definesubmol` and attach the bridging carbon atom once so that when the structure is built it looks like the fragments are actually connected (denoted with red line).

Due to 6-fold symmetry this approach worked out fine, however I wouldn't know how to construct a similar structure around C5 ring as the neighboring carbon atoms won't overlap in this case, obviously.

Trying to use labels (`?[c1]`), I ended up with a mess – I'm not sure it's the correct approach for symmetrical structures at all.

So, what would be the proper way of interconnecting blocks of such symmetrical structures?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
    \setchemfig{
        atom sep = 1.5em,
    }

\begin{document}

\chemname{
    \definesubmol{ph1}{-*6(-(-[,,,,red])=-(-(-)(-[::60])(-[::-60]))=-=)}
    \chemfig{
        *6((!{ph1})-(!{ph1})=(!{ph1})-(!{ph1})=(!{ph1})-(!{ph1})=(!{ph1}))
    }
}
{hexa-\textit{tert}-butyl-hexabenzocoronene \\ six-fold symmetry}

% Using the same approach for another symmetry:
\chemname{
    \definesubmol{ph1}{-*6(-(-[,,,,red])=-(-(-)(-[::60])(-[::-60]))=-=)}
    \chemfig{
        *5((!{ph1})-(!{ph1})-(!{ph1})-(!{ph1})-(!{ph1})-(!{ph1}))
    }
}
{hypothetical structure 1 \\ five-fold symmetry}

% Using labels for linking departure and arrival carbon atoms:
\chemname{
    \definesubmol{ph1}{-*6(-(-[,,,,red]?[c1])=-(-(-)(-[::60])(-[::-60]))=-?[c1]=)}
    \chemfig{
        *5((!{ph1})-(!{ph1})-(!{ph1})-(!{ph1})-(!{ph1})-(!{ph1}))
    }
}
{hypothetical structure 2 \\ five-fold symmetry}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that you need to connect the first ring with the second, and so on. So, you need to use different IDs for all the hooks (labels/nodes) that you want to connect. As from version 1.33, you can use an additional optional argument with `\definesubmol` (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/459223/47927)). Using this functionality, you can first draw your structure putting in the needed hooks and only later connect the rings at these hooks (you may need to compile twice):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

    \setchemfig{
        atom sep = 1.5em,
    }

\begin{document}

\chemname{
    \definesubmol{ph1}{-*6(-(-[,,,,red])=-(-(-)(-[::60])(-[::-60]))=-=)}
    \chemfig{
        *6((!{ph1})-(!{ph1})=(!{ph1})-(!{ph1})=(!{ph1})-(!{ph1})=(!{ph1}))
    }
}
{hexa-\textit{tert}-butyl-hexabenzocoronene \\ six-fold symmetry}

% Using labels for linking departure and arrival carbon atoms:
\chemname{
    \definesubmol{ph1}1{-*6(-@{a#1}=-(-(-)(-[::60])(-[::-60]))=-@{b#1}=)}
    \chemfig{
        *5((!{ph1}{a})-(!{ph1}{b})-(!{ph1}{c})-(!{ph1}{d})-(!{ph1}{e})-(!{ph1}{f}))
    }
    \chemmove{
        \foreach \x\y in {a/e,e/d,d/c,c/b,b/a}
        \draw[red,-] (a\x) -- (b\y);
    }
}
{hypothetical structure 2 \\ five-fold symmetry}

\end{document}
```

[image]